# Can an undirected cycle be made into a tree by adding directions?

Tags: graph-theory

Consider the graph $G=K_3$ on vertices $\{A,B,C\}$. The graph contains a cycle $(A,B,C,A)$ and so is not a tree.

**Original:** Now make $G'$ by adding directions $(A,B),(A,C)$.

**Edited:** Now make $G'$ on the same vertices with edges $(A,B),(A,C),(B,C)$.

$G'$ is acyclic and connected, which (at least in my course notes) is the definition of a tree. Is $G'$ a tree?

Comment: A directed tree is a directed graph whose underlying graph is a tree. In other words, if we "forget" the directions of the edges (make them undirected), we get a graph that is a tree. So, in your case, $G$ is not a directed tree.

Comment: @CoHarp Do you know if there's a term for a structure like my $G'$, where the tree requirements of connectedness and acyclicity are satisfied because of the directions? Or else if there's a justification for the convention of not calling this a tree?

Comment: The starting K3 already has 3 (undirected) edges AB,AC,BC. When you say you add directed edges (A,B) and (A,C), unless you simultaneously delete the previous undirected BC you get a hybrid object with some edges directed and some not. This concept may be studied somewhere but is not a well known graph theory object. [If you do delete undirected edge BC you do get a directed tree]

Comment: @coffeemath I've edited the OP to make $G'$ fully directed, since the hybrid quality isn't what I'm trying to get at.

Comment: @mjc I think “directed acyclic graph” would be the most common. The connected condition isn’t necessary for those, but there is a pretty nice Wikipedia article for them. I’d recommend checking it out and digging around in the references?

Answer (score -1):

If a directed graph with more than one vertex is connected, it cannot be acyclic.

Suppose there are  two vertices X and Y. Then, because of definition of connectedness, there is a path X to Y (call it X .>. Y) and there is a path Y to X (call it Y .>. X).

Join both the paths X .>. Y .>. X - this new path is either a cycle itself or we can obtain cycles from it.

Comment: This proof only works for strongly connected directed graphs (not for some merely weakly connected directed graphs). See distinction here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConnectedDigraph.html#:~:text=There%20are%20two%20distinct%20notions,173). [The connected graph in the present post is strongly connected.]

Comment: Hmm the graph of the present post is actually only weakly connected, it seems.

Comment: I don't follow. Suppose we call your graph $H$. Suppose $H$ has one edge $(X,Y)$. Then where's the path $(Y,X)$? My understanding is that it doesn't exist. And if that's right then there's no cycle.

Comment: @coffeemath True. I assumed connected means strongly connected, because weak connectedness does not imply much for digraphs and is rarely talked about after its definition.

Comment: @mjc in digraphs (strong) connectedness would mean having both paths X .>. Y and Y .>.X

Comment: @mjc Your final G' has the paths A->B->C and A->C. [also two single step paths A->B and B->C which are part of the longer path from A to C already mentioned.] It has no other paths. For example there is no directed path from C to A. [of course the undirected graph underlying your G' has a path between each pair of vertices, making it weakly connected as a directed graph.]

Comment: whoisit, are you saying trees on digraphs are defined as strongly connected? If not, I think my original question remains: why shouldn't $G'$ be called a tree?

Comment: @mjc I'm responding to your last question for "whoisit", who may choose to respond also. The most common definition of tree applies to undirected graphs. There is a separate definition of the phrase "directed tree" already in use, namely a directed graph whose induced undirected graph is a tree. I have not heard of your tree definition for digraphs, but because "directed tree" is already in use it would be unadvisable to attempt a new definition.  Of course if you wish to define it that way in work you do all you need is to give your definition in what you write.

Comment: @coffeemath I think for my purposes I should just mentally replace "A graph G is a tree if G is connected and G has no cycles" with "An undirected graph G is a tree if G is connected and G has no cycles" in my course notes. Thanks to you and whoisit for your help.